# Recent reviewers are being duplicated in the live refresh

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, live-refresh

In [stackoverflow.com/review/](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) it shows recent reviewers for each review task. But if user review consecutively more than one (in between other user review the same task), their image comes more than one time like this:

[image]

Is this a normal behaviour or a bug? If it is a normal behaviour than it does not not look good.

**Edit:** When we see that (more than one image of the same user in the same review task) and refresh it, it shows actual recent reviewer's state (single image for each user).

Comment: It's "alive", think it's a bright new feature probably still bit bugged. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes I see this first time.

Comment: Note that the initial state is always correct, without dupes. So the bug is surely in the code requesting the latest reviewers and updating the placeholders..

Comment: I don't see this on my side, though. I tried to do some review, but I never appear twice in the list.

Comment: @nhahtdh wait a few seconds for the images to start swapping. :)

Comment: @nhahtdh it's done using web sockets, so maybe your browser doesn't support this. (IE)

Comment: I'm using FF. The list doesn't seem to be live over here.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd:Either FF doesn't support web socket also, or the connection is blocked somewhere. EDIT: Probably the connection is blocked for me.

Comment: @nhahtdh I am using Chrome (Version 22.0.1229.94 m). Try it there.

Comment: @nhahtdh, works in FF16 for me

Comment: And now it's dead.. I think we just witnessed a developer playing around. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd No no. It's still shows me. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next build will remove the duplicates and add more slide action.  You must have a web socket enabled browser in order to see this.  You can check your browsers socket support by visiting:  http://websocketstest.com/

If you find the test passes and you're still not getting updates link me your result test ID and I'll have a look.

Comment: Did you also make it slower? It now works, but I'm pretty sure that when I saw that back with the duplicate it changed much more frequently.